# Select element on click

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with selecting the correct element using the .delegate method.

```
<div><span>Some element</span></div>
```

I need to select the div element even when the click event is raised through the span tag. Any ideas, how can I reach the div through the span element?

OK - i see it is not clear, so i try to explain it again:
I have a main DIV. This is the area in which all events should captured und processed. Each "click", "keydown" and "keyup" event should be triggerd by the second level inside the main DIV. This second level is a list of other DIVs.

```
<div id="outline">
  <div id="1"><span>Some Text <img src="could/be/picture" /></span></div>
  <div id="2"><span>Some Text <ul><li>Could</li><li>Be</li><li>List</li></ul></span></div>
  <div id="3"><span>Some Text <a href="#">Even a link</a></span></div>
</div>
```

As u can see, there could be almost every stuff inside thoses DIVs. And i need to make them all unable to trigger events. Means: Click on IMG or UL>LI or A results in an event from the underlaying DIV...(as they were not existing or disabled for events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your callback function, `this` will refer to the `<span>` element. The `<div>` element you're interested in is the parent of the `<span>` element, so use the jQuery [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) function, like so:

```
$(this).parent();
```

Comment: So far so good. But it is possible to click the DIV and/or the SPAN, and i do not know how many levels of other elements are nested in the DIV i would like to select.

Comment: @David Post the code you have in the question? If you're using the same function for the callback regardless of which element was clicked on, you'll want to check the node type - if it's a div, then you already have the element you want; if it's a span, you'll need to traverse up the DOM to get the element.

Comment: Here is my code:

    .delegate(this, 'click.outline', function(e) {
      select_item(e);
    });

..and..

    var select_item = function(e) {
      $selection = $(e.target);
      set_selection_highlight();
    };

Sorry i do not know how to make this post syntax-highlighted

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
$('div').delegate("span", "click", function(){
    var div = $(this).parent();
     //div is the div
});
```

if the event is on the span

```
$('span').click(function(e){
   var div = $(this).parent();
   //You could also use var div = $(this).closest('div'); which works also if the
   //div is not the direct parent of the span
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what i need. Pls have a look at my code sample in the upper post.